# Getting error: "Argument of type '() => () => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to TypeScript. I got an error when I tried to use `useEffect` in TypeScript in React,

> Argument of type '() => () => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.

Why am I getting this error?

Here is my code:

```
const useIsMounted = () => {
        const isMounted = React.useRef(false);
        React.useEffect(() => {
          isMounted.current = true;
          return () => isMounted.current = false;
        }, []);
        return isMounted;
    };
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The function of `useEffect` (`EffectCallback` type) should return `void` or  `() => void | undefined`.

```
function useEffect(effect: EffectCallback, deps?: DependencyList): void;

type EffectCallback = () => (void | (() => void | undefined));
```

In your case, you are returning `void => boolean`:

```
// void => boolean
return () => (isMounted.current = false);
```

To fix it, add scope to the statement of the cleaning function:

```
const useIsMounted = () => {
  const isMounted = React.useRef(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);
  return isMounted;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap `return () => {isMounted.current = false}`.
Shortcut you used looks like this `return () => { return isMounted.current = false;}` so you return boolean value which is incorrect.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).